# USB Drive to Dump Password Hash

Tags: windows

In a DEFCON talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UZQe38u6k8) someone mentioned that they could plug a USB drive into a computer for 5 seconds and have hashes of locally stored passwords. I am interested in how this could be done, so does anyone know of an open-source bit of software that I could load onto a typical USB drive and have it do this? Please note that the scenario doesn't involve a stupid user opening up any suspicious exe's and giving them admin rights.

Specifications: Should be open source, work with any flash drive, and work on Windows.

I understand that this probably looks like I just want to be malicious without writing my own code, but I can only say that I really have no desire to steal Windows logon passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [samdump2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ophcrack/files/samdump2/):

- free + open-source
- should work with any flash drive
- dumps the Windows NT/2K/XP/Vista/7 password hashes

You'll have to launch it though autorun.